# How to get the tweeter time line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeline, twitter-fabric, tweets

if i pass single ScreenName i get the timeline

```
TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] init];
self.dataSource = [[TWTRUserTimelineDataSource alloc] initWithScreenName:@"collisionconf" APIClient:client];
```

But i am trying to pass two ScreenName, then i am not getting the tweeter Timelines.

```
TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] init];
self.dataSource = [[TWTRUserTimelineDataSource alloc] initWithScreenName:@"collisionconf,fabric" APIClient:client];
```

i don't no how to pass the Multiple ScreenNames,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

## Objective C

Please try this link.

https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/show-timelines

Comment: This documentation link they are giving option for one ScreenName. but i want passing multi ScreeName.